# Updating access 2000 database through code in VB6

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2000

I have an application that uses an access 2000 database currently in distribution.

I need to update one of the recordsets with additional fields on my customer's computers.
My data controls work fine as I have them set to connect in access 2000 format. But, when I try to open the database in code, I get an unrecognized data format error.

What is the best way to replace or add to the database on their machines?

Comment: Hi Mark - It is hard to tell without seeing the code you are using to connect to the database, and it would be helpful to know exactly which data controls you are using. :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want to alter the structure of the tables? It would seem to me that altering your recordset would mean nothing more than changing your code. Given the VB6 tag, I assume your front end is VB6, rather than Access, so you'd alter your app and distribute an update to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update an Access database using VBScript, ADO and DDL.

```
strCon="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Example.mdb;" _
   & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass;"

Set cn=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

strSQL="ALTER TABLE Example ADD COLUMN Example Text (20)"
cn.Execute strSQL
```

More connections strings: www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer using DAO collections to updating BE database schemas as it gives you much more control over what you can do.   For example you can easily delete or create tables, records, indexes and relationships. See the [TempTables.MDB page](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/temptables.htm) at my website which illustrates how to use a temporary MDB in your app and has sample code to get you started.

Comment: The advantage of VBScript is that it is very small and easy to transfer (it can even be cut-and-pasted), can be written quickly, and will work on a site that does not have Access installed, only the runtime. You can use DAO with VBScipt, if you prefer.

Comment: I'd much prefer the code to be within the application rather than in a separate file.   I also prefer using DAO as it has a lot more control of an Access database file.  Although that's likely not significant for this particular change of just adding some fields to a table.

Comment: Isn't DAO installed with Jet 4 on all copies of Windows? Thus, is it not the case that you can use DAO within vbScript?

Comment: I've double checked and Jet 4.0 is installed on all versions of Windows from 2000 and newer.   I'm pretty sure the DAO DLLs as well.